# How to fetch index of array using useParams in react.js?

Tags: reactjs

```
[ 

0
: 
{url: 'https://embspace.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/Embcart/Designs/2104202130523_1801-skt.jpg', color: 'Blue, White', material: 'Leather , Beads, Sequins', artwork: 'Organic', effect: 'Artisanal'}
1
: 
{url: 'https://www.embfree.in/designimg-Oct-2019/EMBFREE-ID-2416-011019011928.JPG', color: 'Blue, White', material: 'Leather , Beads, Sequins', artwork: 'Organic', effect: 'Artisanal'}
2
: 
{url: 'https://www.embfree.in/Des-2021/8313-top.JPG', color: 'Blue, White', material: 'Leather , Beads, Sequins', artwork: 'Organic', effect: 'Artisanal'}
3
: 
{url: 'https://www.embfree.in/designimg-Sep-2019/EMBFREE-ID-2411-290919112257.JPG', color: 'Blue, White', material: 'Leather , Beads, Sequins', artwork: 'Organic', effect: 'Artisanal'}
4
: 
{url: 'https://embspace.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/Embca…/Designs/1802202223538_7022-801-fileminimizer.jpg', color: 'Blue, White', material: 'Leather , Beads, Sequins', artwork: 'Organic', effect: 'Artisanal'}
5
: 
{url: 'https://embspace.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/Embca…Designs/08092021234806_3787-top-fileminimizer.jpg', color: 'Blue, White', material: 'Leather , Beads, Sequins', artwork: 'Organic', effect: 'Artisanal'}
6
: 
{url: 'https://www.embfree.in/designimg-Jul-2020/EMBFREE-ID-2754-100720021403.JPG', color: 'Blue, White', material: 'Leather , Beads, Sequins', artwork: 'Organic', effect: 'Artisanal'}
7
: 
{url: 'https://differentdesigner.in/image/cache/catalog/F…%20Design%20Images/EMBFREE1002%20(1)-765x1100.JPG', color: 'Blue, White', material: 'Leather , Beads, Sequins', artwork: 'Organic', effect: 'Artisanal'}
]
```

Array of objects is coming from api response.
i want to create a imageDetail page, so that when clicked on particular image, that image opens in a new route, usually i do this using useParams but in this case no id is present in response.

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router";

const ImageDetail = () => {
    const params = useParams();
    return (
        <div>
            {params.url }
        </div>
    )
}

export default ImageDetail;
```

onclick on particular image should open a new route, so that i can display bigger picture and other details

```
import React from "react"
import { useNavigate } from "react-router";

const ImageRow = ({ image }) => { 
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    return (
        <div onClick={()=>navigate("/image/" + image.index)} className="">
            <img className=" border object-cover items-stretch border-gray-300 rounded-2xl" src={image.url} alt="" />
    </div>
)
}

export default ImageRow;
```

app component for routing

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router'
import HomePage from './components/HomePage'
import ImageDetail from './components/ImageDetail'


function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route index element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path='/image/:index' element={<ImageDetail /> } />
      </Routes>
     
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: `data[params.index].url`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve. And how api works. I guess that in response could be different images at same index.
Best way its permanent id and url of image page. So that the user can always open specific image.
To achieve it in backend should be endpoint to get one specific image. Without it will be difficult and needs some crutches.

Simple way its just make this single photo page unreachable directly, only from previous page where you can get array of images.

And when you got all images you can save this array and allow user to get single page by array index. Like `/images/1`. On the page you can take 1 array element and show image. But for permanent routing its bad idea because I think in array could be different images at same index.
But if it is not and api always return 7 the same images you can make it a permanent url.

But you can create permanent url for image in hard way.

For example you can stringify your object and create some url param. In this param will be saved all image data. Or just pass image data to query params.
This not the best idea but for fun to try api which you cant change, why not.

```js
function createUrlHashFromObject(obj) {
  const jsonString = JSON.stringify(obj);
  const encodedString = encodeURIComponent(jsonString);
  const hash = `#${encodedString}`;
  return hash;
}

function getObjectFromUrlHash(hash) {
  const encodedString = hash.substring(1);
  const decodedString = decodeURIComponent(encodedString);
  const obj = JSON.parse(decodedString);
  return obj;
}


const object = {
  url: 'https://embspace.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/Embcart/Designs/2104202130523_1801-skt.jpg', 
  color: 'Blue, White', 
  material: 'Leather , Beads, Sequins', 
  artwork: 'Organic', 
  effect: 'Artisanal'
}

const urlParam = createUrlHashFromObject(object)
const resultObject = getObjectFromUrlHash(urlParam)

console.log(urlParam)
console.log(resultObject)
```

It would be permanent url for your image.

In 'all images page' you can just use createUrlHashFromObject and pass this string to url.